# I want to create a programme in java that shows me the same substrings from two given strings

Tags: java, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to create a programme in java that shows me the same substrings from two given strings.This programme is givng the StringIndexoutOfBounds Exception.

Here is the exception:

cat

vat

3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Substr.main(Substr.java:22)
```

This is the code i have written.Pls help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Substr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1=new String();
        String s2=new String();
        s1=sc.next();
        s2=sc.next();
        int l1=s1.length();
        int l2=s2.length();
        System.out.println(l1);
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
            int l=i;
            char c=s1.charAt(l);
            int k=0;
            while (c!=s2.charAt(k)) {
                k++;
            }
            char temp=s2.charAt(k);
            l++;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(c);
            sb.append(s2.charAt(l));
            String substr1=sb.toString();
            sb.append(temp);
            k++;
            sb.append(s2.charAt(k));
            String substr2=sb.toString();
            if (substr1.equals(substr2)) {
                String substr=substr1+substr2;
                System.out.println(substr);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the same code twice?

Comment: @Arc676: looks to be. I deleted the 2nd copy. Tushar -- you should look at the line indicated by the exception stacktrace method, line 22 of your program, and see what you're doing wrong there. Or at least indicate which line it is to us.

Comment: Code formatted for readability

Answer (score 0):

If s2 does not contain c,

```
while (c!=s2.charAt(k)) {
    k++;
}
```

will keep increasing k until it is greater than s2.length, causing your error.

Comment: Even if s2 contains c,compiler is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you call `s2.charAt(k)` first you must check if `k < s2.length()`
However I cannot understand what your code must do, can you explain better what you expect as output?

Comment: Teg what i want is that suppose we input 2 strings:cat and bat ; i want the program to output the common string i.e 'at'.